# How to inject reference to IHubContext for.NET Core HostBuilder?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-webjobs, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a self-hosted Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs Azure Function that I am hosting in a Linux Docker container.  At the moment the function is simply processing data from a ServiceBus.  This all works fine.  However, I'd like to be able to post the results of the data processing to certain web clients via Azure SignalR.  I have the Azure SignalR instance set up and can connect to it from my various web clients.

What I'm stuck with, is how to send messages to the SignalR hub from my function.

I have added the SignalR and AzureSignalR services via HostBuilder (and the appropriate connection string is in the appsettings.json file):

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace InSysWebJobHubDataProcessor
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new HostBuilder();
            builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
            {
                b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
                b.AddServiceBus();
            });
            builder.ConfigureServices(b =>
            {
                **b.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR();**
            });

            var host = builder.Build();
            using (host)
            {
                host.Run();
            }
        }
   }
}
```

I believe I had to inject a reference to IHubContext somehow, but do not know how to do this.

How do I add a reference to IHubContext and then access it from within the Function.Run method when needed?

Comment: I have not worked with Azure SignalR, so I might be off, but have you looked at this pattern? https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/31118 . Basically you have to remove static from your function class and method, and inject the dependency through a constructor.

Comment: I followed this approach and there was some progress.  I now get an error complaining that "AddAzureSignalR(...)' was called without a matching call to 'IApplicationBuilder.UseAzureSignalR(...)".  This might point to a fundamental issue with my approach.  I just want to be able to push messages directly from my function, or server. I do not need an web endpoint to be able to send messages from a web client.

Comment: @ProfNimrod did you manage to inject it somehow? I'm struggling with same..

Comment: @Selvirrr sure did - see my answer below.  The new input/output bindings are really handy.

Answer (score 3):

The SignalR dependency needs to be injected using the ConfigureWebJobs action on the HostBuilder, rather than the ConfigureServices action, like this:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService;

namespace InSysWebJobHubDataProcessor
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new HostBuilder();
            builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
            {
                b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
                b.AddServiceBus().AddSignalR();
            });                

            var host = builder.Build();
            using (host)
            {
                host.Run();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my case I'm pulling messages from a Service Bus, and pushing them out to various SignalR groups.  My function signature therefore is:

```
[FunctionName("ProcessQueueData")]
public async Task RunAsync([ServiceBusTrigger("queuename", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]Message message, [SignalR(HubName = "myhub")] IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage> signalRMessages, ILogger log)
```

and I send messages to the SignalR service with:

```
await signalRMessages.AddAsync(new SignalRMessage
{
    GroupName = "groupName",
    Target = "clientFunctionName",
    Arguments = new[] { JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.Payload) }
});
```

Comment: your bottom 2 code snippets were very helpful to me. but for some reason when i try to signaRMessages.AddAsync I get a http 401 response returned

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the SignalR Service Bindings (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-signalr-service) for Azure Functions and add your Hub through `[SignalRConnectionInfo]` attribute for the input binding and `[SignalR]` for the output binding in your Function.Run method to gain access. See https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-signalrservice-extension.

Comment: This looks promising, but I still don't know how to add the reference to the signalr service itself, and reference my hub class.  I added `[SignalR(HubName = "notifications")]IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage> signalRMessages` to my function signature which, once the appropriate references have been added, I should be able to send messages.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Finally success - the new bindings are fantastic and save a lot of work.  The problem was fixed by injecting the dependency differently at startup differently from what I was doing by using ConfigureWebJobs rather than ConfigureServices as shown in the original question.  I'll add the details to an answer as I did not find this approach detailed in any documentation.

Comment: Once you do, I'll share with the content authors so we can make our documentation better. Glad you were able to figure it out though!